# xCode and ImageMagick not working? Linking to project bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, imagemagick

I made project with ImageMagick included. I installed it through macPorts, linked libraries and headers to my project. Everything worked. But when I try to launch my builded app on other computer, where ImageMagick is not installed, it doesn't even opens my app. Says that Os X version is incompatible. If I install ImageMagick to that computer, then app works OK. What should I do to make it working on computers where users does't have ImageMagick? I guess I have somehow to include headers and libraries to my project bundle. But how to do it in correct way to get working? I tried to copy headers and libraries to my project's bundle but then when I try to build it it says that Magick++.h is not found. Can somebody help me?

---

I added ImageMagick files from where `macports` installed it (`/opt/local/lib/` and `/opt/local/include`) to my created folder named `ImageMagick`, then moved that folder to my project and added `ImageMagick/**` to `Library Search Paths` and `Header Search Paths`. Then removed ImageMagick through `macports`. Project builds successfully, but doesn't runs. It shows error in console:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libMagick++.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/development/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OGL-cahltqazoqxhrthkxztsqyvvodge/Build/Products/Debug/OGL.app/Contents/MacOS/OGL
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

Libs added to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` list is in my app's folder and added to my project. Why it searches for it in `/opt/local/lib`?